# Managed metadata language in Office

Tags: managed-metadata, office-integration, language, office

Is it any way to change the language of the managed metadata terms in Office (e.g. Microsoft Word document information panel).

It seems the language follows the installation language and can not be changed. Even after installing a language pack and changing the interface language, the managed metadata was still showing in the install language.

Example: Keywords are defined in english (default) and dutch. Sharepoint site is localized dutch.

If Office install is english all metadata will show english terms. Even after Dutch language pack is installed and all menus show in dutch, the terms show up in english.

Comment: What is the windows language? Also take a look at the managed metadata cache locally: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\TermSets what language is it in, does it show the multilingual properties?

Comment: I deleted all files in the metadata cache and restarted word. That solved the issue. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: awesome, make yourself an answer and mark it as correct so it is more obvious to what you did to fix the issue.